# How access the JSON Object received at angular side?

Tags: angular, object, angularjs-directive

I want to access the Photo attribute from the JSON Object, I am new to Angular and Loopback, I have been trying for Hours but I am not able to access that photo attribute.

Here is the JSON object I am getting from the Server

```
__zone_symbol__state: true
​
__zone_symbol__value: {…}
​​
Photo: "http://192.168.1.11:3000/api/Pictures/images/download/1559895053710.jpg"
​​
email: "test@gmail.com"
​​
emailVerified: false
​​
mobileno: "9490100101"
​​
name: "Testuser"
​​
societyId: "5ca71e45af5f770e103cff5a"
​​
username: "Test1"
```

And Here is the method I am using to access the attribute as in loopback page I have read that they can be accessed by using just '.'

```
var k = this.auth.profiledata();
console.log(k.Photo);
```

The actual output should be this "http://192.168.1.11:3000/api/Pictures/images/download/1559895053710.jpg" when printing the K value
but I am getting undefined.

Output screenshot of k value

[image]

when I stringify the output i am getting 
this 
`Object { __zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: [] }`

instead of the JSON Object

Comment: `console.log(k)`?

Comment: Try logging `k` alone and check if it has `Photo` property in it. Also, check if k is an `object` instead of a string.

Comment: the above JSON object i have presented is the k value that i have printed in console.it has the Photo property but i am unable to grab it. @YashwardhanPauranik

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the `console.log(k)`? Did you check if `k` is stringified or parsed?

Comment: Show us the code from profiledata

Comment: try 
var k = JSON.parse(this.auth.profiledata());

Comment: profiledata()
  {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
      this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/csusers/'+this.getUserId(),{
        headers : new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
      }).subscribe(res => {
        resolve(res);
      },(err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  } @TonyNgo

Comment: {…}
​
__zone_symbol__state: true
​
__zone_symbol__value: {…}
​​
Photo: "http://192.168.1.11:3000/api/Pictures/images/download/1559895053710.jpg"
​​
email: "test@gmail.com"
​​
emailVerified: false
​​
mobileno: "9490100101"
​​
name: "Testuser"
​​
societyId: "5ca71e45af5f770e103cff5a"
​​
username: "Test1"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
<prototype>: {…}
​​
catch: function catch()​​
constructor: function t()​​
then: function then()​​
<prototype>: Object { … } @YashwardhanPauranik it is not Stringfied or parsed

Comment: it's giving out error@AmmarHussain

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: not assignable parameter string @AmmarHussain

Comment: `console.log(k.__zone_symbol__value.Photo);` ? looks to me like photo is nested in another object by your console output.

Comment: while accessing the value __zone_symbol__value it is showing undefined @AvinKavish

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(k))` ?

Comment: i cannot parse k as k is an JSON object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thank You for the help
`this.auth.profiledata().then(k => this.profileData = k);`

The issue was raised due Asynchronous promise catch. i used .then() to complete the promise and get the access to the JSON object